# In an ER Diagram, how do I know when you use one or many?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, diagram

I am trying to understand cardinality in ER diagrams, starting with a simple example of a visitor visiting a city.  Thinking about it, you can have many visitors visiting many cities, so I drew the ER diagram as shown.  Visitor is an Entity with attributes such as name, Visits is the relationship with the VisitorID and CityID as the primary key and other attributes such as date, and City is an entity, with attributes such as country.  This would mean 0 to many visitors can visit 0 to many cities.  Does this mean that in a database with this ER diagram, I would have three tables? One for Visitor, one for City, and one for VisitCity?  Am I understanding the cardinality correctly?

[image: ER Diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you described the relationships correctly.  *N:M* cardinality needs a third table.

Visits could contain other information, too.  For example, since a visitor can't be in two places at once, there might be an associated time period.

Visitor could have another relationship to City -- say, `born_in` with different cardinality, namely *N:1*, meaning many people were born in the same city (but each is born in only one city!)  For that, `born_in` would be an attribute of Visitor.

Answer (score 3):

yes that is correct. your drawing shows 0 to many visitor(s) can visit 0 to many city(s). so in this case you are correct. as you stated you have named your middle-table visitCity.

but lets say you are required to have a database where visitors can visit 1 city only. you would have one-to-many relationship. this means you **don't need to** use a middle-table for that. so you will end up with 2 tables only.

just because something logical like "many visitors can visit many cities" doesn't mean is true. the requirements is what makes these rules (project assigned by the client saying what he/she needs. or if u are still in school, this would be the papers assigned to you wich the story in it). so when creating databases you have to listen/read the requirements very carefully to determine when to use what. but from reading what u have said i think u are going in the right track :)

Comment: Actually you __can__ use a junction table for one to many relationship. Please don't say you can't do that.

Comment: that is something to learn in advance. as you can read he is very beginner in DB and ERD's. so its good to learn little by little not everything at once :)

Comment: Please bear in mind that questions and answers are supposed to help wider audience than only OP. You could always rephrase it to say that you __don't need to__ instead of __can't__.

Comment: fair enough. thank you for your possitive feedback. edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  that's exactly right.

If you wish to keep your DB in 1NF, every time you face yourself with a N x N cardinality, a new table must be created with the keys to both entities.

More info on normalization [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms)